Is @commitlint/cz-commitlint supposed to change the format of my commits?
I am trying to use commitizen with a custom commitlint configuration, and I discovered the @commitlint/cz-commitlint package.
After following the very easy setup steps, it seems like the CLI from commitizen adapted to my commitlint.config.js automatically (only proposing the types of commits I accept from my configuration). But despite my commitlint.config.js proposing another commit format variant from the conventional commit, the commit created always ends up being a strict conventional commit.
Is the so-called adapter is just supposed to check the commit format, or if it is just supposed to verify the format when used with Husky (or by hand)?
